# elasticsearch creating files but not releasing them until I restart the service

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running elastcsearch 0.90.5 and recently I have been having issues with the disk running out of space.  This is not caused by my indexes increasing in size but by the elasticsearch service holding on to the disk space.

If I restart the service the extra disk space is released and elasticsearch will start working again.  The biggest issue with this is that in order to restart the service I have to take down the database.

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to fix it?

Thanks